# img fixed width when making float in IE 8

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I have a problem with fixed image width only in Internet Explorer (I have IE8)

First the image is not appear at all when padding is not defined

Second when i specify padding:5px; for the img it appears like this
[image]

Note that I can't set a special width for image container div because
 below is my code

HTML:

```
<div class="block_div">
    <div>
        <div class="img_about">
            <img src="test_img.jpg" alt="test_img" width="150" />
        </div>
        <div class="img_about">
            about: "Adapted from Betty Crocker".
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img_about{float:left; }
.img_about img{padding:5px; }
```

and if i delete the float from .img_and_text dev it looks normal width:150

Comment: your image source is test_img.php... what is that ?

Comment: @DiederikEEn how so complicated?

Comment: @mlwacosmos I edited it to .jpg, sorry just I was clearing the HTML code from the PHP code, so I mistake,

Comment: I tried your code. It works even without padding... are you sure that the problem is not your image ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.img_about img { width:150px; height:150px; }
```

Using inline width tags is only helpfull for e-mail clients these days afaik...

Comment: hi Joris , I try that before but it didn't work with me, also, i can't specify height because I'm using it because images dimensions is not fixed

Comment: Make a jsfiddle or something related and i can point you further... without that or more code it's hard to give you a more accurate solution i'm afraid. You might want to try an inline style on your image with a width and height to see if that resolves anything.